# Add a new field and Count each category value by QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have point layer contains sub_category field, I'm looking for a trick how to count each category and added it to a new field by QGIS.

Comment: I did it, by using count expression in field calculator

Comment: The difference is count each category, like total of schools, total of hospitals...etc. I created a new field named it "count" then from field calculator I updated it using count expression: count("sub_category", group_by:="sub_category")

Answer (score 1):

I created a new field and named it "subcat_count", then from field calculator count each category by count expression:

`count("tbl_subcat_ar", group_by:="tbl_subcat_ar")`

[image: calculate count features]

and to ensure the calculation is ok, from select features using expression to ensure the calculation is ok:

[image: ensure calculation is ok]